# Second user gets: The database has been placed in a state by user <name> on machine <name> that prevents it from being opened or locked. (Error 3734)

Tags: ms-access, shared-directory

This is my first post in this forum and I'm looking forward for being part of it! I'm a self-learning programmer in VBA (excel and access) and use coding mostly for getting things done much faster.

Now to my problem:
We've changed from MS-Access 2010 to 2013 recently. Since some days I recognized that if I open the Frontend, the back-end is beeing locked by the first user using his front-end on his machine.
The second user isn't able to open nor the back-end nor the personal front-end on his machine by getting the following error

> The database has been placed in a state by user "admin" on machine "xy" that prevents it from being opened or locked. (Error 3734)

The backend is laying on a shared folder and I've only linked tables in the frontend which connects the two files.
As said, the first user is blocking the file - no issue about 255+ users...

Do anyone has an idea what I can change for having different user again access to their frontend at the same time? What's changed between 2010 and 2013?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: PS: could it be that there is a compatibility problem of the laccdb-file due to the fact that every user is named as "admin" when BE is locked (in error message)?

Comment: I found out that every User is signed in as "Admin". If I try 'currentUser()' then everytime "Admin" is showed at every user. Could this be the reason why?